# Having an array receive its own value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to have an array receive its own value plus a specific cell value:

```
myarray(1) = myarray(1) + Cells(2,4)
```

But I get error "13": Incompatible types (translated from Portuguese)

I have verified that if I make it:

```
myarray(1) = Cells(2,4)
```

It works.

The array has been declared as string.

Please help me out figuring out how to do this.
Best regards,

Comment: If the array is declared as string type then do you want to concatenate?Try & instead of + for concatenation. If you want to save number data then why isn't the array a number type?

Comment: What did you `Dim myarray() As ?` Assuming it's arithmetic with Double data type, you can `myarray(1) = CDbl(myarray(1)) + Cells(2,4).Value`

Comment: If your `myarray` is declared as `String`, then you meant to use `myarray(1) = myarray(1) & Cells(2,4)`

Answer (score 1):

If your `myarray` is declared as `String`, then you meant to use:

```
myarray(1) = myarray(1) & Cells(2,4)
```

**If** you want to add `Numeric` values, then first you need to declare:

```
Dim myarray() As Long
```

And afterwards, you can add with `+`, by :

```
myarray(1) = myarray(1) + Cells(2,4)
```

Comment: *(+1)* In any other programming language you'd get a dozen upvotes for this. In VBA it is considered kind of common sense that string additions require an `&` and not a `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, declaring the array as Long did the job. I wanted to add numeric values but was confused with all variable types. I thought String would cover all. Beginner...
Best regards,